# how to use self signed certificates in a winrt app for https communication with iis

Tags: ssl, windows-runtime, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I am pretty new to the hole certification world and i am currently smashing my head against my winrt app to use self signed certificates with my IIS webserver over https.
These are my current steps.

Create certificates: A root, server and a client certificate.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\makecert" -r -pe -n "CN=appCA" -sr CurrentUser -a sha1 -sky signature -cy authority -sv appCA.pvk appCA.cer
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\makecert" -pe -n "CN=appServerCA" -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ic appCA.cer -iv appCA.pvk -sv appServerCA.pvk appServerCA.cer
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\makecert" -pe -n "CN=appclientCA" -a sha1 -sky exchange -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -ic appCA.cer -iv appCA.pvk -sv appclientCA.pvk appclientCA.cer
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\pvk2pfx" -pvk appServerCA.pvk -spc appServerCA.cer -pfx appServerCA.pfx
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\pvk2pfx" -pvk appclientCA.pvk -spc appclientCA.cer -pfx appclientCA.pfx
```

I installed the appCA.cer in the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" of the IIS server and imported the appServerCA.pfx with IIS. I created the https binding using the appServerCA.

On the client WINRT app i added in the appxmanifest

```
<!--Certificates Extension-->
<Extension Category="windows.certificates">
  <Certificates>
    <Certificate StoreName="Root" Content="appCA.cer" />
    <Certificate StoreName="My" Content="appclientCA.cer" />
    <TrustFlags ExclusiveTrust="true" />
    <SelectionCriteria AutoSelect="true" />
  </Certificates>
</Extension>
```

I also added a HttpClientHandler to the HttpClient

```
HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
this.httpClient = new HttpClient(clientHandler, true);
```

but if i call a https url i get the following inner exception:

The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: You need to approach this very methodically.  First, do you need a client certificate or do you just want to use HTTPS?  Next get the server working for HTTPS only.  Then once that is working go for the client cert.  The client cert you provided does not have a private key since it is a cert file.

Comment: I will try to get https running first. 
After that i will try the client certificate.
Do you know if i can still use 
    <Certificate StoreName="My" Content="appclientCA.cer" />
and use the pfx instead of cer?
Or do i have to use CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync?

Answer (score -1):

I have no knowledge of WinRT but client needs to have appCA.cer certificate in trusted root store to trust the server. Also if you need client to authenticate using certificate, you need to use private key corresponding to client certificate in connection. In .NET there is `X509Certificate2` class that can be used, don't know if there is something similar in WinRT world.